# What is the lifetime of a temporary defined in the left argument of the comma operator?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Please consider the following code in C++:

```
struct A {};

int main() {
  return A(), 1 + 2 + 3;
}
```

In the above example, what is the lifetime of the temporary `A()`? Does it live until the semicolon `;`, or is it destroyed immediately?

All that [N4659](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) has to say about this is:

> If the right operand is a temporary expression (15.2), the result is a temporary expression.

Which is not helping me, as I'm asking about the *left* operand.

Comment: Until the semi-colon

Comment: Your title says "the right argument" and your question says "I'm asking about the _left_ operand".

Comment: thank you. fixed it